# Connecting polygon sides with location data

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm attempting to draw polygons on a map with location data as the user moves. I do not want any breaks between the polygons. I need one side of the next polygon to connect to the previous polygon's side. How would I go about this? I have what I've made so far, but I'm unsure how to gather the location data and use that from before to make the polygons connect.

I am using:

```
onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    currentLocation = (new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    if(previousLocation != null) {
        polygonCornerBackLeftCorner = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(currentLocation, widthInMeters / 2, location.getBearing() + 90);
        polygonCornerBackRightCorner = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(currentLocation, widthInMeters / 2, location.getBearing() + 90);
    }
    previousLocation = currentLocation
}

polygonGenerator() {
    PolygonOptions polygon =  new PolygonOptions().add(polygonCornerBackLeftCorner,       polygonCornerBackRightCorner, polygonCornerFrontRight, polyCornerFrontLeft).fillColor(Color.YELLOW);
    getMap().addPolygon(whatsquare);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get a new currentLocation, you'll want to compute the corner points that correspond to it, and you'll want to cache them for later.  If this isn't the first location, then you'll have a pair of cached corner points, and you'll use them plus the new ones to make your polygon and add it to the map, and then cache the new corner points for the next iteration.